# How to display normal date-time in Midnight Commander?

Tags: date-time, midnight-commander

My MC displays modification date time in very strange manner. Sometimes it displays date+year and sometimes it displays date+time. Unpredictable.

How to make it display something predictable?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Adding

```
timeformat_recent=%d.%m.%y %H:%M
timeformat_old=%d.%m.%y %H:%M
```

to `[Misc]` section of `ini` file didn't help.

Comment: It probably tried to copy the format used by `ls` (which displays the year for files older than 6 months), but didn't quite succeed.

Comment: It displays the year for some recent files too...

Comment: Dims answer is correct,but on MC version 4.7.0.2 this is not working.
On MC version 4.8.19 tested and working ok.

Answer (score 1):

Midnight Commander's new settings location:

```
~/.config/mc/ini
```

Your settings was tested and worked as expected.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I had the same issues, made modifications to the file described (~/.config/mc/ini) and it worked.
Old location of ini-file was ~/.mc/ini. Stale file after upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The inconsistent representation is the result of the default `timeformat_recent` and `timeformat_old` settings in `~/.config/mc/ini` (see [this thread where the same issue is discussed](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/midnight-commander-date-format-setting-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss-4175528439/)). I didn't find  [their man page descriptions](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2687#comment:5) useful, but figured out that the former governs how the timestamp of *recently* modified files are formatted, and the latter is responsible for *older* ones. (Found no specifics on this, but I presume "*recent*" here means "*this year*".)

What helped me to change the time format and make it consistent:

1. Open `~/.config/mc/ini`
2. Change `timeformat_recent` and `timeformat_old` settings to the same format string (in my case, to `%F %T`, which is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`)
3. Save `~/.config/mc/ini`
4. Restart Midnight Commander